# Not able to save the file in localhost foler (IIS) in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, iis-8

I am trying to save my project in the localhost to run locally. But i am not able to save the project there from sublime text. i am getting a message like this:

how to solve this? I have the admin permission already.

[image: Here is the screen shot of the message]

Answer (score 1):

Having admin rights and running as administrator are two separate things on windows 7/8/8.1/10.

When you logon to windows, you are handed a "token"/"ticket" which describes what your user is allowed to do - these generally fall into 3 categories:

- User (Normal Users)
- User/Admin (Admin users)
- Admin ("THE administrator")

If you are an administrator, but not the builtin default Administrator (AKA the 500 account, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330 under "SID: S-1-5-21domain-500") - then your programs actually execute as a normal user, but request administrator rights when needed.

What you are seeing is a classic example of a program which has not had its rights elevated - and therefore is still running as a standard user.

To fix it, it should be as simple as opening your program by right clicking it and selecting "**Run As Administrator**"  This means that everything your application does will be done in the context of "THE" administrator, not just of a user who can elevate to administrator if/when needed.

It's a built-in security feature of windows - which while a pain at times, is actually quite useful - even if only for making you stop and think for a second before agreeing to the UAC elevation prompt.